# Excel file getting freeze when i open any WPF window by click on Ribbon

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, vsto

I have one C# EXCEL application made in VSTO. I have several buttons in ribbon which will open respective WPF(xaml) Windows.

My problem is, When I click on any ribbon button then respective WPF page will opens and then I can not access that excel file till that WPF window is opened. Once I close that WPF window then I can able to access excel again, so I want to access excel file even if any wpf window is opened so that I can use other functionalities of ribbon simultaneously.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: But now I am having another problem due to show(). 
For example, suppose my excel application is opened, so when I load my solution the first cell of that excel file will get focus, now when I will click on the button on ribbon which will open a new window using SHOW() method, so problem is newly created window is not getting focused even if I will click on textbox on that window and try to write something it will goes to that back running excel file's focused cell.

Comment: If the cell is in edit mode - you cannot access other forms/taskpanes. it's a known issue. it even happens in excel's built-in feature. you can watch it if you open excel, go to the "Review" tab and press the 'Research' button so the 'Research' task pane will open. now start editing a cell and try focusing on the task pane - you will see it's impossible

Comment: so any way to solve this? because it is mandatory in my application that the window opened using SHOW() method gets a focus, so that user can use controls inside that window.

Comment: Join the club: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521465/the-focus-issue-between-excel-cells-and-excel-customtaskpane-with-webbrowser-control

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helps me to understand my problem.

Comment: can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042680/right-click-is-not-working-properly-on-triview-wpf              ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var window = new MainWindow();

// this will set focus back to excel after window closed.
window.Closed+=(sender, e)=> System.Wndows.Threading.Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();

window.Show();
System.Windows.Threading.Dispathcer.Run(); // push this to the queue so the textbox can be focused
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.